# numpy genfromtxt でutf-8ファイルを読み込む際のUnicodeDecodeErrorについて

Tags: python, macos, numpy

python3.4, OSX 10.9.5, numpy 1.11.0 を用いています。

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("hoge.tsv", delimiter="\t", names=True, dtype=float, converters={1: lambda x: x.decode('utf_8')})
```

を行ったところ、UnicodeDecodeErrorが出ます。

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

hoge.tsvはutf-8できちんとコーディングできています。
一行目がヘッダー、二行目以下は小数や整数が並んでいます。
一行目のヘッダーのところにのみ日本語が用いられていて、
「日付_2015年」「性別」のようなヘッダーがついています。
ヘッダー行を抜かしたファイルを作成したところ、正しく読み込むことができました。

[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001373/loading-utf-8-file-in-python-3-using-numpy-genfromtxt)や[ここ](https://gist.github.com/tkamishima/52f3c1883bdf7d328e53ff2b2d455e0e)のように解決しようとしているのですが、解決できません。

```
python
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

'utf-8'
とpython自体のデフォルトはutf-8であることは確認しています。

dtype=float　の指定などがいけないのでしょうか？
どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか。
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/44126 マルチポスト

Comment: すみません、困っていたので双方に投稿してしまいました。こういったことはやめた方が良いのでしょうか。消した方が良いでしょうか。

Comment: このサイトでは禁止されていません。ただ、回答者に配慮してリンクを貼ると良いのではないでしょうか。過去のメタ投稿もご参考になさってください。http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1766/
余談ですが、teratailでは規約で禁止されているそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。勉強になりました。お手数おかけして申し訳ありません。気をつけます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージから、該当するソースコード部分を見てみます。

`numpy.genfromtxt()` の呼び出しで `names=True` を指定すると、ヘッダ行に対して `_bytes_to_name()` が呼ばれることになります。

**numpy-1.11/lib/npyio.py**

```
# Check the names and overwrite the dtype.names if needed
if names is True:
    names = validate_names([_bytes_to_name(_.strip())
                            for _ in first_values])
    first_line = asbytes('')
elif _is_string_like(names):
    names = validate_names([_.strip() for _ in names.split(',')])
elif names:
    names = validate_names(names)
```

`_bytes_to_name()` ではヘッダ行のバイト列を `ASCII` コーデックにデコードしようとしてエラーが発生する事になります。

**numpy-1.11/lib/_iotools.py**

```
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    def _bytes_to_complex(s):
        return complex(s.decode('ascii'))

    def _bytes_to_name(s):
        return s.decode('ascii')
```

仕方がないので、ヘッダ(カラム名のリスト)を別途作成することにします。

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> with open('hoge.tsv', 'rb') as f:
>>>   header = f.readline().decode('utf-8').strip('\n').split('\t')
>>>   data = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter='\t', names=header, dtype=float)
```

`numpy.genfromtxt()` への入力はバイト列にする必要があるので `open('hoge.tsv', 'rb')` としています。そのため、ヘッダ行を `utf-8` にデコードしています。

Comment: 詳細なコメントありがとうございます。
ヘッダー行の情報を用いるためには、別途作成する、別途読み込ませるしか、ないのですね。。。
勉強になりました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: numpy ではなく、例えば pandas であればヘッダが `UTF-8` エンコーディングでも読み込んでくれます。 `pandas.read_csv('hoge.tsv', delimiter='\t')` ただ、戻り値はデータフレームになりますが…

Comment: なるほど。pandasで読み込んでからnumpyに渡す、というのも一つの手なのですね。